# Different .htaccess rewrite rules depending on a $_GET param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there a way to make different rewrite rules in `.htacess` if a certain `GET` parameter was passed?

For example, if query string is:

`htttp://domain.com/?debug=1`, than `.htaccess` should look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If there is no `debug=1` in query string, than:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Starkeen I have asked if it is possible to realize the construction described in my post. Actually, my frist sentence was a question. I`ll repeat in once again: Is there a way to make different rewrite rules depending on a request GET parameter.

Comment: Do you mean if there is query string in url then it should rewrite to index.php otherwise app/webroot/ ?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# ?debug=1 is present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)debug=1\b [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

# ?debug=1 is not present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)debug=1\b [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l    
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It seems like `QUERY_STRING` is not being mathced. Do I need some apache configurations for it?

Comment: `QUERY_STRING` works in all mod_rewrite versions. Which URL isn't working for you?

Comment: http://take.ms/AqjqV Here is my .htaccess. Here is my website: http://iamaplayer.ru. There is a `die('a')`; in my test php, but if I add hit http://iamaplayer.ru/cup.html?debug=1, I don`t reach it. I still can navigate through all the site.

Comment: You still have `RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]` line in your `.htaccess`  after `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)debug=1\b [NC]` but as you note above I have removed that redundant rule.

Answer (score 2):

You want to match against the query string in a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^debug=1$     [NC]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

For more information, see the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) or [this example](http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html).